# Можно ли через JS в input записать слово, которое не исчезнет при вводе?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В общем, надо дописать в input перед вводом слово, чтобы пользователь вводил уже после него.

Если кому-то интересны подробности для чего это:
Один input используется для ввода страны и города. Надо чтобы при выборе из выпадающего списка страна сохранялась, и шел перебор городов из этой страны. Сохранение происходит, но город начинает вводиться в пустую строку, а надо по маске "страна, город". Как сделать, чтобы в input отображалась страна, и после выбора она не исчезала с поля? На value не реагирует. Для следующего поиска переписываю name у input, так он сохраняет страну в страну, город в город. Примерно так:

```
name={country ? 'city' : 'country'}
```

По сути должно быть что-то не трудное, но это что-то не получается.. Просто надо вывести после изменения имени страну перед городом

мне надо (переформулирую для Вашего понимания), чтобы в одном input вводилась страна (например, Россия), а в другом input появилось: "Россия, " и тут пользователь добавляет город. Но вот это "Россия, " он тоже может удалять (и вот тут в идеале обработчик, что пользователь редактирует страну и тогда значение country стирается).

Comment: вам именно реакт нужен или простой `js` подойдет?

Comment: @ThisMan можно попробовать, если будет не сложно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
~function () {
  var lbls = document.querySelectorAll("label[data-before]")
  var lens = []
  
  for (var q=0; q<lbls.length; ++q) {
    lens.push(getComputedStyle(lbls[q], '::before').width)
  }

  for (var q=0; q<lbls.length; ++q) {
    lbls[q].querySelector("input").style.paddingLeft = lens[q]
  }
}()
```

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

label[data-before]::before {
  content: attr(data-before);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: silver;
  padding-left: .25em;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<label data-before="Страна:&nbsp;"><input type=text /></label>
<label data-before="Город:&nbsp;"><input type=text /></label>
```

Comment: @АленаОсецкая, а в чём тогда вообще проблема?

Comment: в том, что я не могу этого сделать :D и буду рада, если Вы подскажете

Comment: @АленаОсецкая приложите верстку к вопросу. У вас сейчас очень смутное описание, которое порождает много вопросов. Что будет если я удалю значение в первом инпуте. _Но вот это "Россия, " он тоже может удалить_ может удалить в первом инпуте? или втором?

Comment: @ThisMan по сути мне нужно чтобы второй инпут дублировал первый, так будет яснее. Я в реакте новичок, считать получается, а вот записать никак